# What is the meaning of "One for the kitchen, one for the soul"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I want to know the proper meaning of this expression:

> One for the kitchen, one for the soul

Answer (score 4):

This expression means that one pursuit is practical or necessary and another pursuit is a passion or a labor of love. It is a way of describing a healthy balance of life.

Example:

> I am an accountant and a sculptor. *One for the kitchen and one for the soul*.

The word *kitchen* indirectly represents the *stomach* and, more appropriately, *food*. Definition of *food*:

> Any nutritious substance that people or animals eat or drink, or that plants absorb, in order to maintain life and growth.

Definition of *soul*:

> The spiritual or immaterial part of a human being or animal, regarded as immortal.
>
> A person’s moral or emotional nature or sense of identity.

(Oxford Dictionaries Online: [food](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/food), [soul](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/soul))